# Image lazy loading for responsive layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, frontend

I see libs such as

- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
- http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

require you to specify the image width and height, but as our site is using responsive layout, i.e. set image width to 100% via CSS, is it still possible to perform lazy loading? (I've tried the above two libraries and they does not work)

So, what is the recommended approach to do lazy image loading for responsive layout?

Comment: have you tried http://bttrlazyloading.julienrenaux.fr/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [justlazy](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy/) library. You don't have to provide an img tag before you are loading the image. Just define a placeholder of your choice before loading the image, e.g.:

```html
<span data-src="default/image" data-alt="some alt text"
      data-srcset="small/image 600w, big/image 1000w"
      class="justlazy-placeholder">
</span>
```

As you can see, also the "responsive" srcset attribute is supported (see demo on project page). Then register the loading event. If you want to load via scrolling, e.g.:

```js
Justlazy.registerLazyLoadByClass("justlazy-placeholder");
```

If you need more flexibility, there is also a function to start the lazy loading manually.